# multiple open web browser windows or tabs make my Debian 8.5 box very sluggish

Tags: performance, memory, web, browser, debian

I recently installed Debian 8.5 on a 6 core Xeon PC with 24 GB RAM. I use its default web browser, Iceweasel, and I have not added any plugins or extensions, only set its default search engine to Google. Today I noticed that all the open browsers were very slow, for example, if I clicked on a tab, it took forever for the tab to pop up, and if I typed in a new search, it took more than 5 minutes to see the results. Then I realized that I had too many open browser windows/tabs. ( At work where I have Windows 7 running Chrome on a 4 core I7 box with 8 GB RAM, I also experienced similar situations where the PC became sluggish when too many browsers were open. )  Now the htop command tells me that only 1.9GB is being used, less than 10% of available physical RAM. When I close the browsers down to about 20, the remaining ones start to respond very quickly. Here are my questions and hope someone can give me some definitive and convincing answers:

1. If the excessive usage of RAM by the browsers caused them to be sluggish, as many has complained in their searches, why doesn't the OS use the abundant available RAM in my system onto the browsers so that they can "flow" smoothly?
2. Why did they start to respond when I reduced their number to 20? Is there an implicit threshold in the browser application so that beyond that threshold the app will constrain its responsiveness?
3. How in general to tune this box so that applications, browsers in particular, and OS can take advantage of the relatively more RAM ( compared to boxes with 8 or 12 GB )?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Maybe it's your network card, i believe the card type limits the amount of internet capable of being processed. Just a hunch though.

Comment: I guess Firefox/Iceweasel is a 32-bit app, so can consume only about 2 GB of RAM, which you have probably reached. Try loading URL `about:memory` into new tab to see what is causing most of its memory usage.